# How do I get the Winter's Howl in Black Ops 4?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-4

I have been playing Black Ops 4 for a while now, and I have heard a lot of rumors about the Winter's Howl being brought back into the new Zombies map.
I was wondering if it is true that you really can get it, and if so, how? I also just heard about the new map and was wondering how to get it.

Answer (score 1):

To get Winter Howl (Great weapon for slashing zombies) you will need to activate the Pack A-Punch.  You gotta enter special area

But main thing to get that weapon is get access to **4 secret codes**
That you have to by yourself no tricks here

After completing that you have to be alive in 3 rounds and then you will find Winter Howl in a case lying on ground

Well only Panic room code is little bit hard to do.  Rest is all easy.

Comment: well then how do I get a hold of the new Classified map?